# Square matrix row operationrs

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, matrix-equations

What is an n × n matrix A(i, j, c) such that if $B \in M_{n×m}$, then A(i, j, c)B is the matrix obtained from B by replacing its $i^{th}$ row by the sum of the $i^{th}$ row and the {j^{th}$ row multiplied by c?

I am a little confused to what A(i, j, c) is exactly here, i know it is a square matrix but what is i, j, c. I am not sure how to tackle this to figure out what A(i, j, c) is like so any hints to help me get started would be great.

Comment: Start with the identity matrix, then replace the zero in row $i$, column $j$ with the number $c$. That's your $A(i,j,c)$.

Comment: so any number c? what about A(i, j) matrix then--this is another part of the same problem?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "$A(i,j)$ matrix," as you have not mentioned or defined that term.

Answer (score 0):

$A(i,j,c)$ is a matrix that is obtained from the identity $I$ by replacing by $c$ the zero in the $(i,j)^{th}$ position of $I.$ This will give you the desired effect. Here is an example: suppose

$A=\begin{pmatrix}
a &b  &c \\ 
e &f  &g \\ 
 h&k  &l 
\end{pmatrix}.\quad $ Then $\quad A(3,1,-2)=\begin{pmatrix}
1 &0  &0 \\ 
0 &1  &0 \\ 
 -2&0  &1 
\end{pmatrix}\quad $ and $A(3,1,-2)A=\begin{pmatrix}
1 &0  &0 \\ 
0 &1  &0 \\ 
 -2&0  &1 
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
a &b  &c \\ 
e &f  &g \\ 
 h&k  &l 
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
a &b  &c \\ 
e &f  &g \\ 
 -2a+h&-2b+k  &-2a+l 
\end{pmatrix}$

So, $A(3,1,-2)$ multiplies the first row of $A$ by $-2$, adds this to the third row and replaces the third row by the result.

Comment: Yes, that's what I said $A(i,j,c)$ was.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Sorry, I did not read your comment. Should I delete my answer? I am incined to leave it as it is, because  now that I have read the comments, it appears the OP still does not see how to apply the idea.

Comment: It's always a good idea to read the comments before posting an answer, just so you can give credit where it's due. I agree that you should leave your answer up. It would be nice to have some more feedback from OP.